# weaker vs is weaker

Tags: grammaticality

> "Although the synthesized contraint A is still incomplete,
>   nevertheless by incorporating runtime information, it allows
>   synthesizing a constraint weaker than constraint B"
>
> vs
>
> "Although the synthesized contraint A is still incomplete,
>   nevertheless by incorporating runtime information, it allows
>   synthesizing a constraint **that is** weaker than constraint B"

May I know which one is grammatical?

Comment: Both are grammatical, and mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

They are both grammatical. The first one uses "weaker than constrain B" as an adjective phrase whereas the other one makes it a full secondary clause. The second one might be seen in more formal contexts, but either is acceptable.